# Two different providers on the same config file

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, configuration-files

Im using **EntityFramework 6.1.0**

I have **2 providers**. MysqlClient and SQLServerCE, and i need to create **2 different DBContext.** That forced me to create **2 configuration classes** because mysql have some different things. But when i initialize the application, the `Database.DefaultConnectionFactory` is from the **defaultConnectionFactory(config file)**, and i cant specify what provider to take on the daterminated Context.

How to do it?

My config file:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
          <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
     </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Mysql Context:

```
namespace Sistema.DataAccess
{
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(Sistema.DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration))] 
    public class SistemaContext : Sistema.Common.Repository.DataContext
    {
        static SistemaContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<SistemaContext, Sistema.DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration>());
        }
        public SistemaContext()
            : base(GetConnectionString())
        {

        }
        private static string GetConnectionString()
        { 
                return "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=?????;Uid=????;Pwd=????;Port=3306;";//MySQL
        }
    }
}
```

SQLCe Context:

```
namespace Sistema.DataAccess
{
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(Sistema.DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration2))]
    public class SistemaContext2 : Sistema.Common.Repository.DataContext
    {
        static SistemaContext2()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<SistemaContext2, Sistema.DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration2>());
        }
        public SistemaContext2()
            : base(GetConnectionString())
        {

        }
        private static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return "Data Source=C:/teste2.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";//SQLCE
        }
    }
}
```

Mysql Configuration

```
 public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Sistema.DataAccess.SistemaContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            DbInterception.Add(new NLogCommandInterceptor());// guardar logs

            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;

            SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());//Mysql da erro se nao colocar isso.(Pelo que vi da para colocar no App.config tambem.)
            SetHistoryContextFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", (conn, schema) => new MySQLHistoryContext(conn, schema));
        }
    }
```

SQLCE Configuration

```
public sealed class Configuration2 : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Sistema.DataAccess.SistemaContext2>
    {
        public Configuration2()
        {
            DbInterception.Add(new NLogCommandInterceptor());// guardar logs

            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**RESOLVED! (for my case)**

My Config file

```
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"></remove>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

The 2 contexts are the same as the question.
But i removed the `[DbConfigurationType(typeof(Sistema.DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration))]`
from the 2 contexts

Config class 1 (mysql)

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Sistema.DataAccess.SistemaContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new DbConfigurationBase("MYSQL"));

            DbInterception.Add(new NLogCommandInterceptor());// guardar logs

            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; 

            SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());//Mysql da erro se nao colocar isso.(Pelo que vi da para colocar no App.config tambem.)
            SetHistoryContextFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", (conn, schema) => new MySQLHistoryContext(conn, schema));
        }
}
```

Config Class 2 (SQLCE)

```
public sealed class Configuration2 : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Sistema.DataAccess.SistemaContext2>
    {
        public Configuration2()
        {
            DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new DbConfigurationBase("SQLCE"));

            DbInterception.Add(new NLogCommandInterceptor());// guardar logs

            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        }
}
```

And i used your DBConnection Idea to create the connection.

Answer (score 7):

First of all you are using the wrong configuration classes. The DbConfigurationType needs a type inherited from DbConfiguration not DbMigrationsConfiguration<>.

The DbMigrationsConfiguration is really just used for the Migrators and DatabaseInitializers.

```
public class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration()
    {
        this.SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"));

        this.SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", SqlCeProviderServices.Instance);

        this.AddInterceptor(new NLogCommandInterceptor());// guardar logs

        this.SetMigrationSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", () => new SqlCeMigrationSqlGenerator());
    }
}

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyDbConfiguration))]
public class TestContext : DbContext
```

Sadly it is not possible so set multiple DefaultConnectionFactories even with multiple DbConfigurations.

In your case you will have to store the connection strings in the app.config and pass the name to the DbContext constructor.

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestContext()
            : base("name=MyConnectionString")
        {

        }
```

The connection will be initialized based on the provider name for MyConnectionString in the app.config

Or if you don’t want the connection string in your app.config just pass an already initialized DbConnection to the DbContext constructor

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestContext()
            : base(new SqlCeConnection(GetConnectionString()),true)
        {

        }
```

Or if you don’t want to initialize a specific Connection use the DbProviderFactory.

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestContext()
            : base(GetConnection(),true)
        {

        }

        public static DbConnection GetConnection() { 
            var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
            var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:/teste2.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";
            return connection;
        }
```

Comment: Im glad you helped me... but mysql need to use SetSqlGenerator and SetHistoryContextFactory, thatas from DbMigrationsConfiguration... But i maked it, i will post the update as the resolution of the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the respective provider as part of the connection string. I usually do this all in config, so something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="connString1" connectionString="..." providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"<entityFramework>
  <add name="connString2" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"<entityFramework>
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
          <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
     </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: Yes... thats correct but if i need no ConnectionStrings.. All provided by code... Like my GetConnectionString()?