# Using EF DbContext with mysql and sql in the same project

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm working on an ASP.net MVC project using EF in combination with MySql. Now this works just fine on its own but I also want to reference another class library that uses EF with SQL.

When I reference the library EF seems to get confused on what provider to use for each DbContext.

On my MySql DbContext I have the following attribute in order to tell EF this DbContext should be handled by the MySql provider:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
```

Now on the SQL DbContext, I have no attribute. Should I place one on there and if so which one?

Currently, I get the following error:

> The default DbConfiguration instance was used by the Entity Framework
> before the 'MySqlEFConfiguration' type was discovered. An instance of
> 'MySqlEFConfiguration' must be set at application start before using
> any Entity Framework features or must be registered in the
> application's config file.

This is pretty straightforward since the SQL context is used before the MySql one but I can't seem to find a fix on this.

What would be 'Best Practice' on handling this? Or is this something that I should avoid, combining 2 DbContexts in the same project?

**MySql DbContext**

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MySqlContext : DbContext
{
    public MySqlContext() : base("name=MySqlContext")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
    //DbSets....
}
```

**SQL DbContext**

```
public class SqlContext : DbContext
{
    public SqlContext() : base("name=SqlContext")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
    //DbSets....
}
```

**Web.config:**

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlContext" connectionString="some connectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MysqlContext" connectionString="some connectionString" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

I see on the DbProviderFactories it's only saying Mysql.

Comment: Perfectly fine to use multiple dbcontext. Can you post your web.config?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766068/entityframework-two-different-providers-on-the-same-config-file

Comment: I don't have the environment to test in hand. Try put this on top of your SqlContext: `[DbConfigurationType(typeof(System.Data.Entity.DbConfiguration))]`

Comment: @StephenZeng Thanks for the link. I had a quick look at it and will try that later today. I tried to change the attribute really quick but that throws the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not important that how many DbContexts you have(In entity framework 6). Just put connection strings in appConfig or webConfig of startup project.

Example of appConfig with two connectionString with Ef 6.01 & Sql Server and My SQL

```
<configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySqlDB" connectionString="Your My SQL ConnectionString"  providerName="My Sql Provider" />
    <add name="SqlDB" connectionString="Your SQL ConnectionString"  providerName="Sql Provider" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
   <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
```

MySql DbContext

```
public class MySqlContext : DbContext
{
   public MySqlContext() : base("MySqlDB")
   {
      this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   }
//DbSets....
}
```

SQL DbContext

```
public class SqlContext : DbContext
{
   public SqlContext() : base("SqlDB")
   {
      Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   }
   //DbSets....
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit. I have 2 connection strings in the web.config and both providers setup. When I change it you the SqlCeProvider Sql fails also on its own. The Sql server is also not a SqlCompact server.

Comment: Turns out removing the MySql attribute did the trick. Can't believe I didn't try this sooner.. Thanks! Fyi with the System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0 it does not work since we are not using compact.